# How does dojo/request handle html/javascript response?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, request, handler

Actually, we know dojo/request have a property "handleAs" that can handle about:

- text
- json
- javascript
- xml

But how about if the response is a html fragment with javascript embedded? How to handle it?

I am having this problem quite while, I tried to use handleAs: html. The html rendering fine, but I never get the javascript works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I explained you in your other questions, JavaScript is **never** automatically being executed when using AJAX requests (like `dojo/request/xhr`) out of security matters.

If you want to execute JavaScript code that's dynamically loaded, you will have to use the `eval()` function to parse it. However, I also told you already that the Dojo toolkit already has a module to handle XHR requests and execute scripts on it by using a `dojox/layout/ContentPane` and the `executeScripts` property.

However, the use of `eval()` and loading scripts from an AJAX request is considered a bad practice and means your application design probably could be improved. Move the JavaScript onto the parent page (in stead of the fragments) and then you have no problems.

Comment: Yeah. I am trying to move the javascript back to the parents page (top_frame.html) instead of leave it in html fragment (which generated from ajax call). But other issue popped up now. How to bind the newly loaded html fragment's (button) element's onclick event to the parents page's javascript dojo function? Please advice with plenty of appreciate.

Comment: After remove javascript back to parents page, and rewrite dojo function to registry newly loaded html fragment's element in dojo function, eventually made it works. Thank Dimitri M