# Execute JavaScript code that's dynamically loaded in Dojos dijit/Dialog

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, dojo

I have a grid. In each row there is an icon with opens a dijit/Dialog

### The link method in First.jsp:

```
var createDownloadLink = function(updateDescriptorId) {
        var link = put('a[href=#]', _textIcon.getIconNode("download", "action.std.download"));
            on(link, 'click', function() {
                xhr('javaMethod/' + updateDescriptorId, {
                    handleAs : "html"
                }).then(function(data) {
                    dialog = new Dialog({
                        content : data
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                });
            });
            return link;
        };
```

"javaMethod" is method in a Controller which returns a ModelView (of Spring).

The page that should be painted is painted, but only the html part, and the problems is that in this page there is some javascript (dojo) scripts, but it is not painted.

### The painted jsp (but without the javascript part)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([ "js/MyJs",
            "dojo/_base/declare",
            "dojo/ready" ],

    function(MyJs, declare, ready) {

        ready(function() {
            var _view = new MyJs({
                'downloadButton' : 'downloadButton',
                'backButton' : 'backButton'
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="" class="floatbox">
    <div class="h1">
        <spring:message code="text.error.headline" />
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <spring:message code="text.error.description" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div id="downloadButton"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div id="backButton"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

"downloadButton" and "backButton" are not painted because they are defined in the js/MyJs

This is the correct behaviour because "JavaScript is never automatically being executed when using AJAX requests (like dojo/request/xhr) out of security matters." like Dimitri M says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720344/how-does-dojo-request-handle-html-javascript-response)

I read in some threads, that it must be used **dojox.layout.ContentPane**. I tried it, but without success.

### Question

Where should I put the **dojox.layout.ContentPane** or what I have to modify in my code, to get the modal window (dijit/Dialog) displayed with the javascript functionality??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [`dojox/widget/DialogSimple`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/widget/DialogSimple.html#dojox-widget-dialogsimple) can be useful to you as it has the `executeScripts` optional flag.

**Edit**

Instead of using `dojo/request/xhr`, use the `href` attribute of `dojox/widget/DialogSimple`:

```
var createDownloadLink = function(updateDescriptorId) {
    var link = put('a[href=#]', _textIcon.getIconNode("download", "action.std.download"));
    on(link, 'click', function() {
        dlg = new DialogSimple({
            title: "My Title",
            executeScripts: true,
            href: 'javaMethod/' + updateDescriptorId,
        });
        dlg.startup();
        dlg.show();
    });
    return link;
};
```

Comment: How should I used it in my code? Could you put in your answer an example combined with my code please

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put the entire dialog code i.e

```
<div dojoType="dojox.layout.ContentPane">
<div id="" class="floatbox">
    <div class="h1">
        <spring:message code="text.error.headline" />
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <spring:message code="text.error.description" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div id="downloadButton"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div id="backButton"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```